# Storing text file in ipod

Tags: iphone

can anyone please let me know as where the csv file and pdf file is stored in iphone or ipod. Actually my application generates a pdf and csv file but somehow i m not able to know where it is stored in ipod. Please help!!!

Comment: What are you doing to generate your pdf?  Could you perhaps offer the code that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, file system access is sandboxed per application. This means your apps can only read & write within a designated area. You can search for the NSDocumentDirectory via [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains) and get a path back to this direcctory.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply... but my problem is i know the file path in documents directory when on my PC but how do i know where is it generated on the actual device.


Thanks in advance.

Comment: The information above refers to an SDK call that iPhone OS application developers can use to get their app's unique documents directory on the device. You're developing an iPhone/iPod Touch app, right? If that doesn't answer your question, please provide more details about how your PDF/CSV files are being generated.